# Session time out using Javascript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, session-timeout

How can I redirect to the login page when the session has completed?  The code should check that the user sits idle for some time and then does any other client side event.  If it finds this condition, it should check the session time out, and if session completes, redirect to login page.

Comment: Record the time the user logs in server-side and every time a request is made check if the session has expired server-side. If it has redirect them to the login page.

Comment: In what context you want user to redirect to login page?
1. When user don't move cursor? Or
2. When user don't click on any link?

Answer (score 0):

Checking for inactivity on a webpage will be like an attempt to listen   multitude of event. This also means that if there is user interaction the a function (event handler) is going to be called quite a lot of times. If this handler/function is going to some ajax  send/receive stuffs then it could ultimately make your user interface perform poorly.

Why not make the session expiration period  short and auto log out the user after? That way if the user is truly active then most probably there will a request for a page within that time frame. You could also set up a timer based event which when fired will simply send dummy request to server to refresh the session as a way of letting the server know that the user is still active but just not ready to request another page yet. This would be the case where a user is editing a long text or something like that.

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

> **Session Logout after 5 minutes**

```
<sctipt>
    var interval;
     $(document).on('mousemove', function () {
         clearInterval(interval);
         var coutdown = 5 * 60, $timer = $('.timer'); // After 6 minutes session expired  (mouse button click code)
         $timer.text(coutdown);
         interval = setInterval(function () {
             $timer.text(--coutdown);

             if (coutdown === 0) {

                 alert("Session expired User successfully logout.");
                 window.location = "UserLogin.aspx";
             }

         }, 1000);
     }).mousemove();



     var interval;
                 $(document).on('keydown', function () {
         clearInterval(interval);
         var coutdown = 7 * 60, $timer = $('.timer'); // After 6 minutes session expired (keyboard button press code)
         $timer.text(coutdown);
         interval = setInterval(function () {
             $timer.text(--coutdown);

             if (coutdown === 0) {

                 alert("Session expired User successfully logout.");
                 window.location = "UserLogin.aspx";
             }

         }, 1000);
     }).mousemove();
<sctipt>
```

```
<div class="timer">
     Time of session display on page 
</div>
```